# Disable physical menu button(Soft/Hard) in android

Tags: android

There are menu items which are to be used in the action bar, but I dont want the menu to appeared when I press(long press) the menu button which is present on the phone(ex:the left side of the home button in samsung phones).

Can the physical menu button disabled?
If yes, Please guide me how to do it.

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, but before implement this please read [Backwards Compatibility](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/compatibility.html)

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
final int keycode = event.getKeyCode();
final int action = event.getAction();
if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    return true; // consume the key press
}
return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Thank You Abhishek

Comment: Can you explain how the code works?
it worked fine, but I blindly pasted your code.

Comment: `dispatchKeyEvent()` is the first method called by the system.  it will prevent any key events.it will pass the event to an `onKeyListener`. This is when `onKey()` is called. In this case, `dispatchKeyEvent()` will return there and other events will not be called. for more info visit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.Callback.html#dispatchKeyEvent(android.view.KeyEvent)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. But if it's possible, don't do it. LG users expect such behaviour, while Nexus users don't. Don't make them re-learn navigation.

Comment: Still, I suggest you don't do that. Also, what happens when you long-click Recents on LG phone? Does it count as menu click, or something else, which shows overflow menu?